# Wake on Lan (wol) over wifi not working on mac

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, wake-on-lan, osx-yosemite

I am using OS X 10.10 . Wake on network enabled in the Energy saver settings. Asus Router settings done. Packet sniffing shows it is receiving UDP packets on port 9 but it doesnt wake up

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are possibly two issues going on here:

1. You cannot wake from off or hibernate mode the way you can on a PC.  You can only wake it from sleep mode.  Also note that after a certain amount of time sleeping they will hibernate automatically.  You can check this with the `pmset -g` command.  I believe it's the StandbyDelay setting.
2. Only newer Macs support Wake-On-Lan over Wifi.  If your Mac is a 2012 or older model, it probably does not support this feature.

You can check the wording of the Wake for Network Access checkbox in Energy Saver settings.  It will read 'Wake for Wi-Fi Network Access' if your Mac supports this feature.  It will be worded differently if it does not.

Comment: Thanks :) I have an old mac and it seems that is the issue here.